# how to find table column width and apply to another table in the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I'm using 2 tables to create a scroll-able table. But they are 2 separated tables and the column width do not match. How to get the column width from tbody and apply it to thead?

```
<div>
    <table id="header">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>header 1</td>
                <td>header 2</td>
                <td>header 3</td>
                <td>header 4</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="scrollable">
    <table id="body">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>data 1-1</td>
                <td>1-2</td>
                <td>data 1-3</td>
                <td>data 1-4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>data 2-1</td>
                <td>2-2</td>
                <td>data 2-3</td>
                <td>data 2-4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>data 3-1</td>
                <td>3-2</td>
                <td>length testing</td>
                <td>data 3-4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>data 4-1</td>
                <td>short</td>
                <td>data 4-3</td>
                <td>data 4-4</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/revzephyr/3L17sgjw/)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This may be a better alternative - http://anaturb.net/csstips/sheader.htm - there are some examples you can view and play around with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you what you are looking for.  The table width also has to be matched up.

```
//match the table width
$("#header").width($("#body").width());

var bodyTr = $("#body tr:first td");
$("#header tr:first td").each(function(index, value) {
    $(this).width(bodyTr.eq(index).width());
});
```

Here is your modified fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3L17sgjw/4/

Comment: Paul, thank you very much. That is what I am looking for!! Nice and simple too!! I gave it try in my file which has more scripts in it and it doesn't work probably (yet). I will give it more tried and if failed, hopefully you can take a look.

Comment: Glad I could help!  You can remove the console.log statement I accidentally left there :-)

Comment: Paul, I figured out what was wrong when I imply your code to my code. In my other code, I used <th> not <td>. implied version: http://jsfiddle.net/revzephyr/b42vn2nh/16/ ........ by the way do you happened to know how I can keep the column width fixed to the entire list (even if some keywords is being searched). The width changes and adjust to what is shown, which is not very ideal to look at.

Comment: Create a resize() function that contains the code I gave you that triggers after your search filter is done.  You can then call the resize() on the initial table load and after each filter.  By the way, have you checked out datatables.net?  It would be a lot easier then having to do all that on your own.

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply!! I will have to look resize up in cheat sheet and test it. thank you.  I knew about datatables.net and I agree on what you said. But I'm not knowledge enough to understand the background code (the js file) thus it would be difficult to maintain when requested. I tried to cut down codes using datatables, but....without success.

Comment: Paul, I guess I am doing it wrong? Since it is not working. Can you kindly take a look, please? https://jsfiddle.net/revzephyr/b42vn2nh/36/

Comment: Paul, thank again!! Is it possible to do this: th width is same as td width (this is already done with the code you gave me before). And then, td width is stable to itself, regardless of the search function. The new code you modified, adjust the th to td after every search (which is amazing). I want the td to be always stable even if some tr are hidden. hmm....I don't want the td width to change after filter (searched), but I want it to be able to adjust according to window size (browser) that's why I used width:100%. Do it make sense?

Comment: I believe this would take care of the problem.  The resize no longer has to run after every search.  The width gets applied to every td on the body table.  https://jsfiddle.net/b42vn2nh/44/  The problem is that the width only got put on the first table row, and when that was hidden the browser recalculated the columns width for the table.  There might be a better way to optimize applying the cell widths, but that was the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: Paul you are totally awesome! If it is okay with you can I ask more questions?

Comment: Yes what is your question?

Comment: Thanks in advance, Paul. I have made 2 new adjustments, A) "on window resize, resize table (baisically resize th)" [test line21-26] is not functional and B) using if statement, when "srowCount=0" display new row. B) is working with unknown error, beyond search result "0", it goes back to "1" when there is no rows. Not sure why. (try to enter random letters in input box and you can experience it. http://jsfiddle.net/revzephyr/b42vn2nh/48/ Can you kindly take a look and give advises.

Comment: The resize just needs a reference to the function like this, `$(window).resize(
    resizeTable
   ); ` need to omit the ().  http://jsfiddle.net/b42vn2nh/49/

Comment: Okay....it turned out to be not a great idea to set the column width for every TD. Because the actual data has 800*9 columns and it had a hard time loading. Here is my "new" question, if you are still available to help. Is it possible to write a javascript, where the user can set how many columns there will be, and then set the width (col style) for each?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a class for every column with something like this:

```
$("#header td:nth-of-type(1)").addClass("column1");
$("#body td:nth-of-type(1)").addClass("column1");
//And so with every column you want
```

And then set the fixed width value for that class.
The correct way of doing this would be with a for loop to do not duplicate the same two lines for every column.

But i think that it would be easier if you just add your 'scrollable' class to the tbody without keeping thead and tbody separated in different divs.

Comment: Thanks Manuel. I understand your method of giving a class and set a fixed width value. However, I don't intend to set a fix value. And for the separated divs, so that the header will not be scrolled when the list is longer.